# Dissable buttons with GTK

Tags: user-interface, gtk, gnome

Hi guys i am starting with gtk and i need to disable a button after the first click.

I have two buttons, the 1st one begins the data inyection using the usb and the second one kills the process. After the 1st click the data infection button must be disable. I am using  an option called gtk_widget_set_sensitive(widget, FALSE|TRUE). After this the button is always disable but i can not understand why?.

Here is my code:

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>

pid_t pid, pid2;
double a;

static void button_clicked2 (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
    pid2=pid+1;
    kill(pid, SIGTERM);
    kill(pid2, SIGTERM);
}



int button_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
  g_print("clicked\n");
  pid = fork();
  //Here we begin te data transmission from our usb port... ( the port must be initialized before we run the code)
  if ( pid == 0 )
{

      execlp("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", " cat /dev/cu.usbmodem1421 -9600 > data1.txt", (char *)NULL );

     printf("hello");

    }
    return pid;
}


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GtkWidget *window;
    GtkWidget *button;
    GtkWidget *box1;

    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    box1 = gtk_hbox_new (FALSE, 0);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), box1);


    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("button 1");

    a=g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (button_clicked), (gpointer) "button");
    if(a==9)
    {
     gtk_widget_set_sensitive(widget, FALSE)

    }

    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(box1), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show (button);


    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("button 2");

    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(box1), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);



    g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (button_clicked2), (gpointer) "button 2");

     gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX (box1), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);



    gtk_widget_show(button);
    gtk_widget_show(box1);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

I believe the button stops before the click or maybe i do not understand how the function calls are working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks drahnr :) that was very helpful :).

At the end i modified the example on the GTK tutorial page and i declared another button. So handling a separated button and your observation were the right answer.

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <stdio.h>




GtkWidget *window;
GtkWidget *button;
GtkWidget *button2;
GtkWidget *box1;
pid_t pid, pid2;
double a;

static void button_clicked2 (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{

    g_print ("capture\n");
    g_print ("stop\n");
    pid2=pid+1;
    kill(pid, SIGTERM);
    kill(pid2, SIGTERM);
}

static void button_dissable (GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{

    gtk_widget_set_sensitive(button, FALSE);
}



static void button_clicked(GtkWidget *widget, gpointer data)
{
  g_print("clicked\n");

  pid = fork();
  printf("hello");
  //Here we begin te data transmission from our usb port... ( the port must be initialized before we run the code)
  if ( pid == 0 )
{

      execlp("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c", " cat /dev/cu.usbmodem1421 -9600 > data1.txt", (char *)NULL );

     printf("hello");

    }
}





int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{


    gtk_init (&argc, &argv);
    window = gtk_window_new (GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);
    box1 = gtk_hbox_new (FALSE, 0);
    gtk_container_add (GTK_CONTAINER (window), box1);


    gtk_container_set_border_width (GTK_CONTAINER (window), 10);
    button = gtk_button_new_with_label("button 1");

    g_signal_connect (button, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (button_clicked), (gpointer) "button");
    g_signal_connect_swapped (button, "clicked",G_CALLBACK (button_dissable),button);




    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(box1), button, TRUE, TRUE, 0);
    gtk_widget_show (button);


    button2 = gtk_button_new_with_label("button 2");

    gtk_box_pack_start (GTK_BOX(box1), button2, TRUE, TRUE, 0);



    g_signal_connect (button2, "clicked", G_CALLBACK (button_clicked2), (gpointer) "button 2");

     gtk_box_pack_start(GTK_BOX (box1), button2, TRUE, TRUE, 0);



    gtk_widget_show(button);
    gtk_widget_show(button2);
    gtk_widget_show(box1);
    gtk_widget_show(window);
    gtk_main();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `gtk_widget_set_sensitive(button, FALSE)` in the **callback** you connect to your button.

---

```
if(a==9)
{
 gtk_widget_set_sensitive(widget, FALSE)

}
```

Does not make any sense. Read the [manual](https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/unstable/gobject-Signals.html#g-signal-connect).